# Silverstripe - How To Create Pages as Part of a Deployment?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a silverstripe based web application which is under active development and gets deployed regularly to our dev, QA, UAT etc environments. At the moment we have automated jobs for those deployments which copy the files, do a composer install and run dev/build all from the command line so that my development changes can easily be deployed to our various environments.

What is missing is that when I create a new page, I have to manually go to the environment after deployment and log in to to /admin Pages -> Add New -> Select Page Type -> Fill in the form and click Publish.

Is there a way to automate that process? I cannot find any info in the docs or anything in the code which defines that these pages exist - do they exist solely in the database? The Page names and paths are always the same since other parts of our app need to know where to point to in order to function.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to "deploy pages".

If you simply want to mirror your dev db and assets, you can use [sspak](https://github.com/silverstripe/sspak)

If your module wants to make sure, some default pages or dataobjects exist, you can use the method `requireDefaultRecords()` on your DataObjects. This is run on every dev/build and checks if it should add something. The docblock of `DataObject::requireDefaultRecords()` says:

> Add default records to database. This function is called whenever the
>   database is built, after the database tables have all been created.
>   Overload this to add default records when the database is built, but
>   make sure you call parent::requireDefaultRecords().
>
> @uses DataExtension->requireDefaultRecords()

I often add data locally when I don't know the actual content of pages. But for setting up a given site structure or data structure, there is a [module called Populate](https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-populate), where you can define your data in yml files and run a buildtask to add it to the DB.

This module is quite flexible, you can either wipe away a database table and re-fill it, or you can check if a given page exists and update it etc.